# Accessing the nested level of sealed class in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, sealed-class

I have a sealed class

**MyEvents.kt**

```
sealed class MyEvents<out T : Any>{
    sealed class HelloBroadcasting<out T : Any> : MyEvents<Nothing>() {
        sealed class FeatureSegments : HelloBroadcasting<Nothing>() {
            class SegmentationCourseSeekChapterChange(val context: Context) : FeatureSegments()
            class SegmentationChapterNameClicked(val context: Context, chapterName: String) : FeatureSegments()
            class SegmentationChapterSelectionFromChapterList(val context: Context) : FeatureSegments()
        }
    }
}
```

**I call the sealed class**

```
sendTheEventEvent(MyEvents.HelloBroadcasting.FeatureSegments.SegmentationChapterNameClicked(mContext,it.textDirection.toString()))
```

I am trying to get the event received as

```
fun sendCleverTapEvent(event: MyEvents<Int>) {
        when(event){
            is MyEvents.HelloBroadcasting.FeatureSegments.SegmentationChapterNameClicked -> test(event.context,event.) // ---> Here I am not able to access the name
            is MyEvents.HelloBroadcasting.FeatureSegments.SegmentationChapterSelectionFromChapterList -> TODO()
            is MyEvents.HelloBroadcasting.FeatureSegments.SegmentationCourseSeekChapterChange -> TODO()
        }
    }
```

I am not able to access the name in the receiving part. How to do this properly when the nested level is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make `chapterName` a property:

```
- chapterName: String
+ val chapterName: String
```

Comment: Damm, I missed that... Thanks .... I'll mark the answer accepted  :)